# Spring Security : org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User cannot be cast to Person

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I am working on a Spring-MVC application which uses Spring-Security. In that I need to get the currently authenticated user's object so I can use setUser() method. In the below mentioned code, there is a method named getCurrentlyAuthenticatedUser(), and in that I have error at getPrincipal as it cannot cast from springframework.security.core.userDetails.User to Person(My class which has all person details). I checked on internet for various solutions for this, but none of them are work/suitable for implementation I have done. My implementation of authentication matches the one mentioned in the blog below. I have pasted all possible classes which can be useful.

Blog :

http://krams915.blogspot.de/2012/01/spring-security-31-implement_3065.html

Person Class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="person")
public class Person implements UserDetails{

    private static final GrantedAuthority USER_AUTH = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER");

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "person_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "person_seq_gen",sequenceName = "person_seq")
    private int id;


    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;


    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

 @Transient
    private final String PERMISSION_PREFIX = "ROLE_USER";
    @Transient
    private List<GrantedAuthority> authorities;

    @Transient
    private String role;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "person1")
  private Set<Notes> notes1;

    public Set<Notes> getNotes1() {
        return notes1;
    }

    public void setNotes1(Set<Notes> notes1) {
        this.notes1 = notes1;
    }
}
```

LoginServiceImpl :

```
@Transactional
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class LoginServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService{

    @Autowired private PersonDAO personDAO;
    @Autowired private Assembler assembler;

    private static final GrantedAuthority USER_AUTH = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER");

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException,DataAccessException {
        Person person = personDAO.findPersonByUsername(username);

        return assembler.buildUserFromUserEntity(person);
    }
}
```

Assembler class :

@Service("assembler")

```
public class Assembler {
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    User buildUserFromUserEntity(Person userEntity){
        String username = userEntity.getUsername();
        String password = userEntity.getPassword();

        // Long id = userEntity.getId();
        boolean enabled = userEntity.isActive();
        boolean accountNonExpired = userEntity.isAccountNonExpired();
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = userEntity.isCredentialsNonExpired();
        boolean accountNonLocked = userEntity.isAccountNonLocked();

        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));

        User user = new User(username,password,enabled,accountNonExpired,credentialsNonExpired,accountNonLocked,authorities);
        return  user;
        }
}
```

// I get error in below method at getPrincipal
PersonServiceImpl :

```
@Service
public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService {

    private PersonDAO personDAO;
 @Override
    public Person getCurrentlyAuthenticatedUser() throws Exception{
       Authentication a = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

 if(a == null) {
     System.out.println("Authentication Failure");
     return null;
 }else {
     System.out.println("Authentication is not null");  
     Person currentUser = (Person) a.getPrincipal();  // throws nullpointer exception here
     if(currentUser == null){
         System.out.println("Getauthenticcated User didnt find user");
         return null;
     }else {
         System.out.println("We have currently authenticated user");
         return currentUser;
     }
    }
```

Spring Security-xml

```
    <import resource="servlet-context.xml" />

    <!-- Global Security settings -->
    <security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

    <security:http pattern="/" security="none" />

    <security:http create-session="ifRequired" use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" disable-url-rewriting="true">
         <security:port-mappings>
        <security:port-mapping http="80" https="443"/>

    </security:port-mappings>
           <security:session-management session-fixation-protection="migrateSession" invalid-session-url="/invalidSession.html">
            <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="3" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" expired-url="/sessionExpired.html"/>
        </security:session-management>
           <security:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/note/add" always-use-default-target="true" authentication-failure-url="/login?error"/>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="LoginServiceImpl" />

    </security:authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
                class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
                <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="LoginServiceImpl"/>
    </beans:bean>


</beans>
```

Comment: Hi, can you confirm that you see the message `Authentication is not null` followed by a *NullPointerException* on line `Person currentUser = (Person) a.getPrincipal();` ? Could not it be a `ClassCastException` ?

Comment: Hello, I don't see that message. Finally I found a way around it. Everything was correct with spring security implementation. I couldnt get around casting problems, so I just retrieved the user's username via authentication object. Passed it to DAO to retrieve the Person object and used it to save notes. Not optimal, but works for now.

Comment: Why do you create a `User` instance when your `Person` class already implements `UserDetails`?

Comment: @Orici please don't keep reposting the same stuff in multiple questions with minor changes, or at least delete your older questions. It makes it very hard to answer. And above all, as you've been asked already, please post full details of the error and always include the stacktrace if you have one. Thanks.